# AngularJS: how to refresh all visible controllers on page after state change? - Navigation after login

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router, state

I managed to get it working by using a directive `navbar` and including it in my index.html, but after login, when I make a state change, my navbar does not get updated. If I refresh the page manually, then it reflects the changes.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

**index.html**

```
<navbar></navbar>
<div class="container">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

**navbar.html**

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a ui-sref="login" ng-hide="navbar.auth">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="navbar.Logout()" ng-show="navbar.auth">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was not using a directive for the `navbar` and instead just using multiple views for the same state. This automatically reloads all views on state change.

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view="nav"></div>
<div class="container">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

And so the first page after login, gets the navbar as a second view, using the same template and controller as any other main state.

**pivot.routes.js**

```
routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

export default function routes($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('pivot', {
            url: '/pivot',
            views: {
                '': {
                    template: require('./pivot.html'),
                    controller: 'PivotController as pivot'
                },
                'nav': {
                    template: require('../nav/nav.html'),
                    controller: 'NavController as navbar'
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Further reading: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views